# Remove status message after PDF has been generated with C# and Rotativa

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-3, rotativa

We have a "export to pdf" button that when clicked generates a lengthy report. The PDF is generated with [Rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa). We need to display a message while the PDF is being generated (easy) and dismiss it once the PDF has been generated (hard). I do not see any hooks in the ViewAsPdf() method that will enable us to dismiss the message after the PDF is generated. Has anyone been able to solve this problem? What hooks, if any are available?

I am trying to hide the message after the PDF has been generated.

Thanks with much appreciation

**The Message in the View**

```
<!-- The message we show to the user after they click the export to PDF button -->
<div id="pdfProcessing" style="display: none; border:1px solid #666666;">
                <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/logo.png")" alt="@Index.PdfProcessing ..." />
                <h2>@Index.PdfProcessing ...</h2>
                <div>@Index.PdfProcessingMessage</div>
</div>
```

**The Javascript button click handler**

```
//Displays message when the export to PDF button is clicked
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#export-pdf-btn").click(function () {

        $('#pdfProcessing').show();
    });
</script>
```

**Controller Action**

```
// Export to PDF button action handler
public ActionResult Pdf(string districtId, int year, int month)
{
    return new ViewAsPdf("Index", EducationReportTasks.BuildViewModel(User, districtId, year, month, true))
    { 
        FileName = districtId + "-" + year + "-" + month + "-report.pdf"
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should download the file using javascript. Perhaps you could use something like this: https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload